# vehicle.location.local_frame return none

Tags: drone.io, dronekit-python, dronekit, mavlink

I use px4 AC3.5.4 with raspberry.
My target is autonomous positioning drone in his local frame without global (gps).
I arming drone in GUIDED_NOGPS mode and takeoff.
I make request for my position in local frame with next command: vehicle.location.local_frame, but it return 'north=none, west=none, down=none'
What did i do wrong?

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You have said that you are working with GUIDED_NOGPS mode so the GPS is disable.

Are you using PX4Flow sensor for position hold? 
You need a sensor to get the local position.

[PX4Flow](http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-px4flow-overview.html) sensor is official supported from [ardupilot](http://ardupilot.org).